# Check if grouped items in list are not unique with LINQ

Tags: c#, list, group-by

I have a list of a class, the class is something like this:

```
public class Reg
{
    public string GID;
    public string name;
}
```

I grouped the list based on `GID` by this code:

```
 List<Reg> fLst = new List<Reg>(lst.Where(x => x.GID.Trim() == ""));
 var gLst = lst
     .Where(x => x.GID.Trim() != "")
     .GroupBy(u => u.GID)
     .Select(grp => grp.ToList())
     .ToList();
```

Now I need to find those groups that don't have unique names with LINQ? I mean those groups that have items with different names with LINQ.

Comment: Group the groups by name. Look for name-groups with more than one item.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare counts and do it like this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp18
{
    public class Reg
    {
        public string GID;
        public string name;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Reg> youList = new List<Reg>();

            //Test data
            youList.Add(new Reg
            {
                GID = "grp1",
                name = "1"
            });
            youList.Add(new Reg
            {
                GID = "grp1",
                name = "1"
            });
            youList.Add(new Reg
            {
                GID = "grp1",
                name = "2"
            });
            youList.Add(new Reg
            {
                GID = "grp2",
                name = "1"
            });
            youList.Add(new Reg
            {
                GID = "grp2",
                name = "2"
            });
            youList.Add(new Reg
            {
                GID = "grp3",
                name = "3"
            });
            youList.Add(new Reg
            {
                GID = "grp3",
                name = "3"
            });

            var gruppedList = youList.Where(x => x.GID.Trim() != "").GroupBy(r => r.GID).Select(grp => new { A = grp.Key, B = grp.Select(r => r.name).ToList() }).ToList();
            var grpNameWhereNotUnique = gruppedList.Where(r => r.B.Count != r.B.Distinct().Count()).Select(r => r.A).ToList();
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(grpNameWhereNotUnique));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

So, `grp1` has values 1,2,1 `grp2` has values 1,2 and `grp3` has values 3,3

The result says:

```
["grp1","grp3"]
```